# WMI Object with another object as property

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I have a below powershell wmi query and I want the vbscript equivalent query for the same.

```
(get-wmiobject ProcessorStatus -namespace root\wmi).PerfStates.State
```

**ProcessorStatus** WMI class contains *Perfstates* property which is an object of **PerformanceStates** WMI class. **PerformanceStates** WMI class contains *State* property which is again an object of another class called **PerformanceState**. This class contains *Flags, Frequency and PercentFrequency* properties which are our final values we are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, you have valid MOF available.

```
set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\wmi")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from ProcessorStatus",,32)
        for each objItem in colItems
            <your code>
        next
```

Comment: this basic structure I am aware of.

Comment: How will I know that? You should have written what you already know. and why downvote for that?